# Using eclipses's FileFolderSelectionDialog

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I'm trying to use eclipse's FileFolderSelectionDialog because I need to have a dialog that can select both folders and files. Having 2 buttons (one for folders (DirectoryDialog) and one for files (FileDialog)) just feels like bad UI design to me, hence the use of the FileFolderSelectionDialog.

However, there doesn't seem to be any sort of example code anywhere that show how to use it properly. Even after importing all the dependencies for the FileFolderSelectionDialog into my project, I'm still getting an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.dialogs.FileFolderSelectionDialog.<init>(FileFolderSelectionDialog.java:237)
at com.cardboardengine.modulebuilder.ui.ImportAssetsDialog$1.widgetSelected(ImportAssetsDialog.java:76)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:240)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
at com.cardboardengine.modulebuilder.ui.ImportAssetsDialog.open(ImportAssetsDialog.java:43)
at com.cardboardengine.modulebuilder.ui.MainWindow$2.widgetSelected(MainWindow.java:115)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:240)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
at com.cardboardengine.modulebuilder.ui.MainWindow.open(MainWindow.java:52)
at com.cardboardengine.modulebuilder.ui.MainWindow.main(MainWindow.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workbench has not been created yet.
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.getWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.dialogs.FileFolderSelectionDialog$FileLabelProvider.<clinit>(FileFolderSelectionDialog.java:43)
    ... 16 more
```

I'm not exactly sure how to resolve this error. The getWorkbench function returns and IWorkbench type, and according to the API reference, this interface isn't supposed to be implemented by clients (not entirely sure how that's relevant). My code for calling the FileFolderSelectionDialog is simply:

```
FileFolderSelectionDialog assetLoc = new FileFolderSelectionDialog(shlImportAssets, true, IResource.FILE | IResource.FOLDER | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            assetLoc.open();
```

So I suppose my question in summary is: how do I use the org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.dialogs.FileFolderSelectionDialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are writing a plain SWT app. The class in question cannot be used in that context. You can only use it in an app built on top of Eclipse Rich Client Platform (RCP). RCP has the concept of a workbench and sits one layer higher than SWT.

In case you are interested in RCP, I don't have a specific article or book to recommend, but if you search for terms like "Eclipse RCP Tutorial" you will find plenty of hits.